# Achimedean valuations of a number field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $k$ be a number field with $[k:\mathbb Q]=n=r_1+2r_2$, where $r_1$ is the number of the real embeddings, and $r_2$ the number of pairs of complex embeddings. So we have $r_1+r_2$ number of Archimedean valuations $\{v:v\mid\infty\}$.

Let $k_\infty=\prod_{v\mid\infty} k_v$.
For $t\in\mathbb R^\times_{+}$,
we have $\prod_{v\mid\infty}t\in\prod_{v\mid\infty}k_v$.

My problem is the following. what is the value of $\prod_{v\mid \infty}|t|_v?$
Is it equal to $t^{n}$?

Comment: I think this is quite a strange question. Let $k = \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$. Then $\prod_{v\mid\infty}k_v \simeq \mathbb R^2$. Now you're taking $t = \pi$, for example, and asking for a sensible interpretation of it inside $\prod_{v\mid\infty}k_v$. The only possible answer is that $\prod_{v\mid\infty}|t|_v = t^n$, but I hope this example illustrates that this answer has nothing to do with the arithmetic of $k$.

Comment: By contrast, if you take $t = 1+\sqrt{2}\in k$, then $\prod_{v\mid\infty}|t|_v = (1+\sqrt 2)(1-\sqrt 2) = -1$. This is because there are two embeddings $k\to \mathbb R$. But there is only one field embedding $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$. So if you were to insist on viewing $1+\sqrt{2}$ as an element of $\mathbb R$ (i.e. if you were to favour one of the two embeddings over the other), then you would get the answer $(1+\sqrt 2)^2$, which is definitely not what you want!